# Spring Boot AOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am having some issues trying to get my advice to execute. I tried several different pointcuts to no avail. The "@EnableAspectJProxy" seems to be working and detects my aspect. Any advice is appreciated.

I am using spring-boot-aop-starter.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExecutionTimeLogger {

    private Logger logger;

    public ExecutionTimeLogger() {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
        logger.info("HEY");
    }

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")
    public void controller() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* edu.x.y.z.server.web.controller.*.*(*))")
    public void methodPointcut() {}

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *)")
    public void requestMapping() {}

    @Around("controller() && methodPointcut() && requestMapping()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        String name = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        try {
            sw.start();
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            sw.stop();
            logger.info("STOPWATCH: " + sw.getTime() + " - " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to match any method that is within my package and is annotated with the @RequestMapping annotation. I have tried the very generic match any and all methods without any luck too.

Here is a sample of a method that the advice should be applied to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/analysis", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get analyses available for the current user")
JsonModelAndView getAllAnalyses(HttpServletRequest request)
```

Comment: What is it you expect to happen? Do you have an example of a method that you want to be intercepted and it is not?

Comment: I expect the methods within my package "edu.x.y.z.server.web.controller" and annotated with "@RequestMapping" to be intercepted. The advice should provide output via the console of the execution time and the name of the method that was intercepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get this resolved. I ended up creating a small spring application to test the use case with the specific pointcuts to remove other potential barriers. I found that my pointcuts needed some adjusting.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExecutionTimeLogger {

    private Logger logger;

    public ExecutionTimeLogger() {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
        logger.info("HEY");
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void requestMapping() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* edu.x.y.z.server.web.controller.*Controller.*(..))")
    public void methodPointcut() {}

    @Around("requestMapping() && methodPointcut()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        String name = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        try {
            sw.start();
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            sw.stop();
            logger.info("STOPWATCH: " + sw.getTime() + " - " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the big difference was the annotation pointcut.

Comment: Yes that is a big change. Your initial attempt only matches in classes with the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to set proxyTargetClass=true (assuming your controllers do not have an interface). Use your own `@EnableASpectJAutoProxy` or set `spring.aop.proxyTargetClass=true`.

Comment: I tried to use this approach, but did not have any luck.